# Bring text before the second special character in SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, substring, special-characters, trim

I have a column that looks like this:

```
ss pullover jaq:rwbwht:40 
ribbed cttn 5608:navy:10.5 
shorts:black:xl
s:pigment wash mushroom:l  
t tote bag:mushroom:1size
```

I need to extract the string before the second `:`, so that it would look like this:

```
ss pullover jaq:rwbwht
ribbed cttn 5608:navy   
shorts:black  
s:pigment wash mushroom  
t tote bag:mushroom
```

How do I do that?

I tried `RIGHT` and `substring` functions, but they only bring text up to the first `:` not until the second `:`.

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc)

Comment: Will it always be 2 colon characters? (Never 1 or 3?)

Comment: @jarlh yes, there are always 2 colon characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option using regexp:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(<YOUR_COLUMN>, '^[^:]*:[^:]*') FROM <YOUR_TABLE>;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `split_part()` to split string based on `:` and then concat them again.
Or second way is to use substring with regexp_instr() like below-

```
select split_part('ss pullover jaq:rwbwht:40',':',1) ||':' || split_part('ss pullover jaq:rwbwht:40',':',2) option1,  
substring('ss pullover jaq:rwbwht:40',1,regexp_instr('ss pullover jaq:rwbwht:40',':',1,2)-1)  option2
```